# vegan doesn't recognise column names, but it also does recognise them

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to run RDA analysis using the R package 'vegan'

If I go with the below, using column headers, I get the error "object "width" not recognised". Suggesting that I haven't imported column headers properly.

```
rda(width+height~age+weight, data=mydata)
```

*But*

if I go with the below, it works, so obviously it recognises headers

```
rda(mydata$width+mydata$height~mydata$age+mydata$weight)
```

Similarly, other packages recognise headers for example the below works fine.

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(height, width))
```

Presumably it's an issue with the use of "data=mydata". I'm baffled and feel it's probably something super simple I'm overlooking, but I have tried and tried to no avail. It was going fine the other day.

Answer (score 3):

As per the help page of `rda` the left hand side of your formula should be a community data matrix, and `data` should specify a data frame containing the variables on the right hand side of the formula.

As such, when you pass column names to the left hand side of the formula (e.g. your first line of code), `rda` is not looking within `mydata` for those columns and so fails.

In your second line of code you specify where `width` and `height` are found, so it is able to run.

You could run it like this:

```
response <- data.frame(height=mydata$height,width=mydata$width)
rda(response ~ age + weight, data=mydata)
```

Have a look through the documentation for `cca/rda` and you'll see example code - try to get your data into the same format as the examples.

Comment: arrrgh thanks!

I had used the examples format quite some time ago, but it must have been with a different approach towards RDA.

Looks like its working now, just tweaking it here and there :) 

Thanks again.